# What contagious diseases can be diagnosed by x-ray test on chest?

Tags: bones, chest, test, ribs-ribcage

I'm going to work in a pasta manufacturing company/factory. Egyptian law states that I must not catch any contagious diseases to be able to work there. I was asked to do a chest x-ray test.

The report of the test says:

- Clear both lung fields and both C/P angles.
- Normal cardio-thoracic ratio.

I wonder how can doctors diagnose any diseases from this test?! It's just a test on bones of the rib cage.

I'm also asked to do a stool test and I found this test is reasonable. For me, the only reason for the chest test is that the government wants to collect money from people by doing these tests.

Comment: Have you googled this? Chest Xrays don't just show bones. Diagnosis of lung diseases by CXR - just typing that yields scores of links...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A chest X-ray can detect changes in the lungs that occur in certain infections, such as pneumonia, tuberculosis, tularemia, aspergillosis, histoplasmosis, plague, etc ([American Journal of Rentgenology](https://www.ajronline.org/doi/full/10.2214/AJR.13.11463)).

In most cases, additional tests, such as sputum and blood tests, are needed to confirm an exact diagnosis.

[Here](https://www.radiologymasterclass.co.uk/tutorials/chest/chest_pathology/chest_pathology_page3) and [here](http://www.radiologyassistant.nl/en/p50d95b0ab4b90/chest-x-ray-lung-disease.html) you can see which other lung abnormalities (lung cancer, edema, COPD..) a chest X-ray can detect.